# Comparing #define giving incorrect result

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

I have defined one variable which gives me output as below.

```
iPhone 4 >> 4
iPhone 5 >> 5
iPad >> 999
```

Function used is as below.

```
#define iPhone4Or5 [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568 ? 5 :
        ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480 ? 4 : 999)
```

When I NSLog variable `iPhone4Or5`, it gives me correct result for iPhone 5, however when I make compare it gives me wrong result...

```
if (iPhone4Or5==999) {
    NSLog("Its iPad version");
} else {
    NSLog("Its iPhone version");
}
```

When I run above with iPhone 5 or above, it always gives me NSLog as **Its iPad version**.

Any idea why I am getting WRONG compare result?

I am defining variable in `prefix.pch`

**Note:**

If I execute `NSLog("iPhone4Or5==%d", iPhone4Or5)`, I get output as `iPhone4Or5==5`

Comment: What do you do when the device/simulator is in landscape mode? Wouldn't the height be something else? I.e. the width of portrait mode..

Comment: Don't use macros here. The way you are using them is an anti pattern. ;)

Comment: And if you insist on using macros, make sure you use enough parentheses to avoid operator precedence problems and other pitfalls.

Comment: @matsr : My App is potrait mode only :D :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having problems with operator precedence - your macro needs parentheses:

```
#define iPhone4Or5 ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568 ? 5 : \
        ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480 ? 4 : 999))
```

Better still, avoid this and other common macro-related problems and use a function instead:

```
int iPhone4Or5(void)
{
    const int height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    if (height == 568) return 5;
    if (height == 480) return 4;
    return 999;
}
```

Comment: just curious, what parenthesis is making problem? My concern is when I get value as 5, why compare gives wrong result?

Comment: its working perfectly, but just curious what parenthesis is making difference?

Comment: When you expand your macro for `if (iPhone4Or5==999)` the `== 999` term gets evaluated as part of the second ternary expression, instead of being applied to the whole compound expression as defined in the macro - that's why you need parentheses. This is really basic C stuff which you should know if you plan to do any serious programming in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Log the value of `[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height` and check if it 480.

Or you can use these.

```
#define IS_IPAD ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] && [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 

#define IS_IPHONE5 ((( !IS_IPAD && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568))?YES:NO)
```